# cakephp mongodb: Notice (1024): connecting to localhost: 27017 failed: unknown error in mongodb_source.php

Tags: cakephp, mongodb

i'm getting the following error when i run my website:

```
Notice (1024):connecting to localhost:27017 failed: Unknown error [APP\plugins\Mongodb\models\datasources\mongodb_source.php, line 201]Code | Context        } catch(MongoException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            trigger_error($this->error);$host   =   "localhost:27017"
$e  =   MongoConnectionException
MongodbSource::connect() - APP\plugins\Mongodb\models\datasources\mongodb_source.php, line 201
MongodbSource::isConnected() - APP\plugins\Mongodb\models\datasources\mongodb_source.php, line 251
MongodbSource::read() - APP\plugins\Mongodb\models\datasources\mongodb_source.php, line 876
Model::find() - CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 2130
MotorDevelopmentsController::search() - APP\controllers\motor_developments_controller.php, line 13
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 87
```

Can anyone tell on what i'm doing wrong? Thank you.

I have placed the Mongodb database driver (version 0.4) for cakephp from https://github.com/ichikaway
in \merry_flowers\plugins. I renamed it to Mongodb (camelized).

In \merry_flowers\config\database.php

```
    <?php
     class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'merry_flowers_db',
);

public $mongo = array(
    'driver' => 'mongodb.mongodbSource',
    'database' => 'student_db',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 27017

);  

  }
      ?>
```

i'm using a mysql database (for everything) and mongodb (only for reporting purpose) for my website.

in model: motor_development.php

```
    <?php
class MotorDevelopment extends AppModel {
    var $name ='MotorDevelopment';
    //var $primaryKey ='student_id';
    var $useDbConfig='mongo';
    //var $useTable=false;
    var $mongoSchema=array(
                            'student_id'=>array('type'=>'integer','primary'=>true,'length'=>10),
                            'Draws freehand pictures'=>array('type'=>'string','length'=>1),
                            'Cuts and paste pictures'=>array('type'=>'string','length'=>1)
                            );

}


?>
```

merry_parents_controller.php

```
  .....
  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'motor_developments', 'action'=>'search',$student_info));
```

controller: motor_developments_controller.php

```
      <?php
class MotorDevelopmentsController extends appController{
    //public $MotorDevelopment;
    public $name='MotorDevelopments';

    public function search(){
        echo 'SEARCH';
        var_dump($student_info);
        $x=$this->MotorDevelopment->find('one',array('conditions'=>array('MotorDevelopment.student_id'=>12)));
        $this->set('x',$x);
        $this->set(compact('x'));
    }
}
?>
```

Mongodb database details:

```
mongodb database name: student_db
collection: motor_developments
the record i have inserted:
         student_id:12
         Draws freehand pictures:B
         Cuts and pastes pictures:B
```

Comment: I've given up trying to get mongodb to work with cakephp. Instead, I realized that i can store that data (for reporting purpose) in mysql. So, now I can query it to produce the report. As, therealomrose (in my cakephp mongodb driver installation question)said, there is no documentation on the net to get both mysql and mongodb  to work with cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of difficulties to make it work but I finally did! I created a github repo with a simple template with the latest CakePHP version with the MongoDB datasource working:

https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-MongoDB-Template

If you download this template and it doesn't work it will be a problem with the MongoDB server running in your localhost.

Hope you can make it work.